распаковка f-строк при парсинге
Имеется обычный скрипт на питоне, допустим, test.py, внутри которого всего 2 строки:
a = "qq"
b = f"{a} bb"

Есть ли возможность прочитать этот файл, чтобы распарсилась f-строка? Чтобы прочитать не b = f"{a} bb", а b = f"qq bb"

Возможно вам будет достаточно выполнить скрипт, и узнать значение переменной?

@Chorkov реальная задача гораздо шире - репозиторий, в котором куча файлов, в которых куча f-строк, которые надо бы распарсить при чтение этих файлов

Стандартными средствами python (типа импортом) - нет. Можно читать построчно построчно, парсить регулярными выражениями.

А, ну хотя можно попробовать ast.parse, из полученного AST дерева вытаскивать f-строки.

@insolor вот сейчас пробую эту библиотеку, спасибо, надеюсь найду там ответ

@insolor можно ещё вызвать исполнение файла, но это такое себе решение

@Зарина при исполнении файла у вас сразу значения в f-строки подставятся, как и при импорте

@insolor да, и этот вариант не подходит (т.к. кучу другого кода исполнять не надо), попробую через AST, спасибо за наводку

А без выполнения всего другого кода получить значение f-строки всё равно невозможно, так как оно может явно или - что самое страшное - неявно зависеть от любого другого кода
